# A simple explanation for passing params in callback functions

Tags: javascript, callback

I know this question has probably been asked before, but I can't correctly understand or implement the solutions listed. I'm trying to create custom confirm boxes that work like this:

```
// This is what a Dialog looks like
var dialogMessage = {
    head: 'Dialog Heading',
    body: 'Dialog Message Body',
    yah: function(parameter){ something(parameter); },
    nah: function(parameter){ somethingElse(parameter); }
};

// This is how the confirm boxes are created and output to the user
function confirm(Dialog){
    // Render code goes here
    /*
        Here, we listen to see if the OK button is clicked. 
        If so, we execute the defined yah() function
    */
    $("button.OK").click(function(){
        if( typeof( Dialog.yah ) === "function" ){
            Dialog.yah();
        }
    });
    /*
        Here, we listen to see if the Cancel button is clicked.
        If so, we execute the defined nah() function
    */
    $("button.cancel").click(function(){
        if( typeof( Dialog.nah ) === "function" ){
            Dialog.nah();
        }
    });
}

// This is how we use the function
confirm( dialogMessage );
```

Basically what I want to know is how to properly pass parameters in the `Dialog.yah` and `Dialog.nah` functions, so that the function bodies can properly use them.

Comment: doesn't `Dialog.yah('some value');` work?

Comment: It would, but the point is that the `confirm()` function won't know about the parameters passed to the `Dialog.yah()` function. That's why I can't explicitly say `Dialog.yah(parameter);`.

Comment: @user2254 What exactly you want to pass to `yah`?

Comment: so.. where will these parameters be coming from? who will provide them ?

Comment: In this example, I'm trying to tell the `confirm()` function to run `Dialog.yah()` using the `parameter` specified in the `dialogMessage`. I can't explicitly refer to the parameter when defining the `confirm()` function because the presence of the parameter is arbitrary. This `Dialog.yah()` in particular may need a parameter, but another one in a later confirm box may not. Does that make any sense?

Answer (score 0):

Just like other normal functions.

```
Dialog.yah("OK");
...
Dialog.nah("NOOOOOOOOOOOOOO");
```

Also, you don't have to create a function wrapper simply to invoke other functions. You can simply make them as values in the object like this

```
var dialogMessage = {
    head: 'Dialog Heading',
    body: 'Dialog Message Body',
    yah: something,
    nah: somethingElse
};
```

Now, `Diaglog.yah` and `something` are one and the same. So, you are indirectly invoking `something`.

**Edit:** As I understand from the comments, you have a problem knowing the parameters being passed to the functions.

Lets say, you are calling `Dialog.yah` which is actually the function `something`. Then, you can design `something` with [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) like this

```
function something() {
    var param1 = arguments[0], param2 = arguments[1]...;
}
```

The function can accept any number of parameters, but it doesn't have to explicitly mention them in the signature. If the number of arguments accepted is lesser than expected then the function may decide throw an error.

Comment: The thing is, the `confirm()` function acts as a kind of "factory" for producing confirm boxes. This means that the number of arguments passed into the `Dialog.yah()` or `Dialog.nah()` is variable. How can I tell the `confirm()` function to run `Dialog.yah()` using the parameters `Dialog.yah()` is provided, without an explicit reference to them?